Why does decrease by 1 ( -- ) and equals one less ( -= ) not do the same when working with pointers?
In this first example, with -=, this works as expected:
Image with result
int value = 3;
int *ptr = &value;
printf("%d\n", ptr);
*ptr -= 1;
printf("%d\n", ptr);
printf("%d\n", value);

But in this other example, with --, the value of the pointer itself decrements, and the value of "value" stays the same:
Image with result
int value = 3;
int *ptr = &value;
printf("%d\n", ptr);
*ptr --;
printf("%d\n", ptr);
printf("%d\n", value);

This is not a big deal of course, but I'm interested in hearing about the differences between two operations that many think are identical.

It’s basically just down to how these get parsed; * binds more tightly than -= but less tightly than --, so you get *(ptr--).

@nneonneo hey lol

C operator precedence

C's operator precedence rules say that postfix decrement binds more tightly than pointer dereferencing, so *ptr-- means *(ptr--), not (*ptr)--. If you write the latter, then it will do the same as -=.
For reference:



Precedence
Operator
Description
Associativity




1
--
Suffix/postfix decrement
Left-to-right


2
*
Indirection (dereference)
Right-to-left


14
-=
Assignment by difference
Right-to-left




ooo thank you for the fun keyword! I'll look into this.

@alter_igel How is it now?

-- *ptr would also get the expected result.

@Bodo In this case it would, since the value of the expression isn't used, but if it were used then it wouldn't.
